# Struts2 client side validation with i18n

Tags: internationalization, struts2, client-side

I have to perform some client side validation.
The error messages should need to appear based on client language.

Currently i have hardcoded the messages in the javascript code.
How do i access the property files from javascript?

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Javascript is a scripting language, I dont think that you will be able to access property files, via java script as property files 
are on the server.

Comment: i don't thik that is possible

Comment: I see some solution using jquery http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using internationalization but it's on server side. First of all identify the when you are processing the request identify the user language and display the appropriate message. refer the following example. http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-i18n-or-localization-example/